# Bash: How to check if a zip file contain a specified path/file.ext?

Tags: bash, unzip

I've to handle 46 .zip file according to their internal structure.

The first usefull check to branch the elaboration is check if a specific file is presente in the .zip.

Actually i'm unzipping and testing the existence of unzipped file.

**But, I ask you, is there a way to check if a file is inside a zip file without extract it entirely, using only bash commands?**

Comment: `unzip -l` lists all files in a `zip` file.

Comment: @pfnuesel: and how to check for a specific file?

Comment: `unzip -Z1 file.zip | grep file`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To check for specific file, you can combine `unzip -l` with `grep` to search for that file. The command will look something like this

```
unzip -l archive.zip | grep -q name_of_file && echo $?
```

What this does is it lists all files in `archive.zip`, pipes them to `grep` which searches for `name_of_file`. `grep` exits with exit code `0` if it has find a match. `-q` silences the output of grep and exits immediatelly with exit code `0` when it finds a match. The `echo $?` will print the exit code of `grep`. If you want to use it in if statement, your bash script would look like this:

```
unzip -l archive.zip | grep -q name_of_file;
if [ "$?" == "0" ]
then
    ...
fi;
```

Comment: unzip takes lists of files itself, including when you list with -l so you don't need grep:   unzip -l archive.zip name_of_file

Comment: The first version (with `&&`) will not work as expected in case `name_of_file` is not part of the ZIP archive. Since whenever the left-hand side of `&&` already fails, the right-hand side is not even executed.

Comment: @chris that is indeed true, but if you only want to find check for that file and if file is not found, you won't see anything on screen, since `echo` will not be executed. On the other hand, the second script shows the example with semicolon, since in that case you need the output

Comment: This will also match any file `"something$name_of_file"`

Comment: This method will fail if your filename has newline characters or any other non-standard character

Answer (score 3):

on command-line you can try:

```
$ if [[ `unzip -Z1 audio.zip | grep help.mp3` ]];then echo 'yes';fi
```

if the `help.mp3` is found the output would be `yes`

see:

```
help [[
```

on [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)

Comment: Warning: this will also match `selfhelp.mp3` and similar.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do is:

```
if [[ -n `unzip -Z archive.zip file 2>/dev/null` ]]; then
    echo 'yes'
else
    echo 'no'
fi
```

Comment: maybe also rediredt stdout:  like 
```
  >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 2):

Most of these methods work as expected, except when the filename has non-standard characters such as newlines. Example:

```
$ unzip -l foo.zip
Archive:  foo.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  05-06-2020 12:25   foo^Jbar
        0  05-06-2020 12:25   foonbar
---------                     -------
        0                     2 files
```

As you see, the newline character is replaced with `^J`. You could start using this in your `grep`, but then you need to know all other [Control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) by heart.

The following methods works always:

```
$ unzip -Z foo.zip foo$'\n'bar &>/dev/null && echo true || echo false
true
$ unzip -l foo.zip foo$'\n'bar &>/dev/null && echo true || echo false
true
```